# Manually add records to django_session table

Tags: django, django-models

I need to manually add records to `django_session` table. With my own SQL.

Can I leave `session_data` column empty? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Why do you need to add records outside Python? Have you considered just writing a form and view to add session records, and using that as an API?

Comment: I can't imagine why you think you need to do this. The session table is for, well, sessions: that is, data stored alongside an actual user browsing the site. There's not much benefit in using the sessions table for data that isn't actually associated with a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_data` contains the actual data for the session. With Django sessions, the cookie that tracks the session actually just contains an ID, which points to a record in the database that contains the actual session data. `session_data` should not be blank; you can store a blank string, but it should be serialized the same way the Django database backend does it. Unfortunately, this involves pickling the data (with Python's `pickle` module) and then converting that into a base-64 representation, so it may be non-trivial to do this *outside* of Python.

Why must you use your own SQL? Why not write a script (preferably a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)) that taps into Django's sessions framework to create your objects?